# "Import" by code ClassMapping to Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'd like to use `NHibernate.Asp.Identity` library for NHibernate, I'd like to extend standard `IdentityUser` class - however all mappings written in this library are done with `ByCode.Conformist.ClassMapping<>`. Is there any way that I could "import" these mappings (maybe during database configuration?) so I could map my `ApplicationUserIdentity` with Fluent like that:

```
public class ApplicationUserIdentityMap : ClassMap<ApplicationUser>
{
     public ApplicationUserIdentityMap()
     {
          HasMany(x => x.MyProp);
          ...
     }
}
```

where `ApplicationUser` is:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ... my properties
}
```

and mappings to `IdentityUser` are written with `ByCode.Conformist.ClassMapping<>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, that this should not be an issue. What we at the end need - is the **`Configuration`** object - provided with both *(or even more)* mapping 1) from Fluent as well as 2) from `Mapping-by-code`. Based on these resources:

- [Fluent configuration](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration)
- [NHibernate 3.2 Mapping by Code – Basic Mapping](http://lycog.com/programming/nhibernate-32-mapping-code-basic-mapping/)

This could be the configuration:

```
// standard Fluent configuration
var fluentConfig = FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
        .ConnectionString(@"Data Source=.;Database=TheCoolDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"))
    .Mappings(m =>
        m.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyAwesomeEntityMap>());

// return the NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration
var config = fluentConfig
    .BuildConfiguration();

// now Mapping by Code

// firstly the Mapper
var mapper = new NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.ModelMapper();

mapper.AddMappings(Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(IdentityUser)) // here we have to get access to the mapping
    .GetExportedTypes());

// finally the mapping just read
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

// extend already existing mapping
config.AddDeserializedMapping(mapping, null);

// the ISessionFactory
var factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Extend:

Not sure how to mix the fluent and mapping by code for purposes of inheritance...

But there is even more narrow way how to configure `fluently` and inject some `mapping-by-code` parts:

```
// Let's start with mapping-by-code,
// so firstly create the Mapper
var mapper = new NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.ModelMapper();

mapper.AddMappings(Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(IdentityUser)) // here we have to get access to the mapping
    .GetExportedTypes());
// create the mapping
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

// standard Fluent configuration
var fluentConfig = FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
        .ConnectionString(@"Data Source=.;Database=TheCoolDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"))
    .Mappings(m =>
        m.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyAwesomeEntityMap>())

// here we INJECT the HBM mapping
// via call to built in ExposeConfiguration(Action<Configuration> config)
     .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.AddDeserializedMapping(mapping, null));

// the ISessionFactory
var factory = fluentConfig
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: that works - however i can't add SubClass mapping with fluent (like public class ApplicationUser : SubclassMap<IdentityUser> { .. } )

Comment: I see now... hmmm, never tried that. I would say, combination of two mappings for **inheritance** purposes would not be easy. I do not know how ;(. Meanwhile, I at least extend the answer with even more "fluent" configuration - injecting the mapping-by-code... sorry I do not have more precise answer ...

Comment: thats the way I have done it before. Seems like the only way is to rewrite library mappings to fluent.